# $√2|z|≥|Rez|+|Imz|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I just came across this simple inequality which I am finding it difficult to prove.

For any complex number z I need to prove that the following inequality holds $$√2|z|≥|Rez|+|Imz|$$ I would much appreciate if someone could give me a hint to solve this. Thanks